# finding the middle element out of 3 (finding maximum product of a triplet)

Tags: time-complexity

This is my first time asking on SO so if there are mistakes or something wrong with my post please tell me and i will edit to make it better.

I need to find the maximum product of a triplet in an array, in the best complexity i think i did ok but i got stuck in the final part because i couldn't find the element in between the 3 ( middle in positives and middle in negatives), finding maximum and minimum isn't much of a problem i suppose but if there are mistakes also in that i would happily take any notes. my code: ( we can assume that the array has a minimum of 3 elements)

```
public static int findTriplet (int[] arr){
    int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE , max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE , max3 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE , min2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE , min3 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int countPos = 0 , countNeg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i]> 0){
            countPos++; //counter for positive values
            if(arr[i]>max1){ //updating maximum value 1
                max2 = max3;
                max3 = max1;
                max1=arr[i];
            }
            else if(arr[i]>max3){ //updating maximum value 2
                max2 = max3;
                max3 = arr[i];
            }
            else if(arr[i]>max2){ //updating maximum value 3
                max2 = arr[i];
            }
            else{ //else if the value is negative
                countNeg++;
                if (arr[i]<min1){ //updating minimum value 1
                    min2 = min3;
                    min3 = min1;
                    min1 = arr[i];
                }
                else if (arr[i]<min2){ //updating minimum value 2
                    min3 = min2;
                    min2 = arr[i];
                }
                else if (arr[i]<min3){ //updating minimum value 3
                    min3 = arr[i];
                }
            }

        }
    }
    int maxPositive = Math.max(max1, Math.max(max2, max3));
    int minPositive = Math.min(max1, Math.min(max2, max3));
    int maxNegative = Math.max(min1, Math.max(min2, min3));
    int minNegative = Math.min(min1, Math.min(min2, min3));
    if(countPos==3){
        return max1*max2*max3;
    }
    else if(countPos == 2){

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help, would appreciate any help and tips in finding the middle value with minimum time complexity and of course would appreciate any notes for improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need three minimum. 
Product of two minimums and a maximum will be maximum(given that the minimums are negative.) Otherwise the answer will be the product of three maximums.

A solution:

```
 public int maximumProduct(int[] nums) {

    int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max3 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    int min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int min2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for(int i : nums) {
        if(i >= max1) {
            max3 = max2;
            max2 = max1;
            max1 = i;
        }
        else if( i <= max1 && i >= max2) {
            max3 = max2;
            max2 = i;
        }
        else if( i <= max1 && i <= max2 && i >= max3) {
            max3 = i;
        }

        if(i <= min1) {
            min2 = min1;
            min1 = i;
        }
        else if(i <= min2 && i >= min1) {
            min2 = i;
        } 
    }

    return Math.max(max1*max2*max3, min1*min2*max1);    
}
```